# Why is my data frame still empty?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to make a data frame from the following code, but it is always empty and I'm not sure why. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
step_size = 0.01
start = [100]
iter_list = list(range(10000))

for i in iter_list:
    start.append(start[i] - step_size)

iter_list2 = list(range(len(start)))

variable_step = pd.DataFrame()

for i in iter_list2:
    variable_step[i] = ((start[i]*step_size)/100)
```

Comment: how many rows and columns do you expect in the dataframe?

Comment: I want a data frame with I column and 10,000 rows

Comment: I got it to work using np.zeros instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have some sort of confusion about what a dataframe is. Your code doesn't seem to recognize that a DataFrame is a two-dimensional data structure, with rows and columns.

When you do `variable_step[i] = ((start[i]*step_size)/100)`, you're creating a new column in `variable_step` with column label set to the current value of `i`, and initializing every element of that column to `((start[i]*step_size)/100)`, since `((start[i]*step_size)/100)` is a scalar.

Creating a new column this way doesn't add more rows. It just adds more values to the existing rows - all 0 of them. Each new column you create has length 0, because you never create rows.

If you want me to tell you how to fix this, well, I can't, because I don't know what you were even trying to do.

Comment: I would like `variable_step` to be a data frame with 1 row and 10,000 columns. I am trying to fill it with `((start[i]*step_size)/100)`

Answer (score 0):

You initialize empty data frame here:

```
variable_step = pd.DataFrame()
```

Assuming your intention is to put list into a data frame, you should:

```
variable_step = pd.DataFrame(start) # or any other list you need
```

Also, you address items by index in the data frame in the last loop to assign values while data frame is empty.
Use .append() instead